# How can I prevent orgmode re-sorting all my headings when I enter a `.org` file? Org startup variables are ignored

Tags: org-mode

While trying to solve this problem, Iv'e followed [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/11801), running `cd ~/.emacs.d/elpa &&  find org*/*.elc -print0 | xargs -0 rm` and recompiling elpa. But the undesired behaviour is still there and now this error shows up:

```
File mode specification error: (wrong-number-of-arguments #[(arg &optional invisible-ok) \306=\203\0    \306=\204\0\307 \210\310
!\210 \211\311X\203 \0\312\313!\210\311V\203]\0
\314V\203]\0o\204]\0\211W\204S\0o\204S\0
\203G\0\315 \210\202K\0\316\311!\210 \211\2024\0)
S\202 \0)\317!\207 [this-command last-command invisible-ok outline-level start-level arg outline-up-heading push-mark outline-back-to-heading 1 error Already at top level of the outline 0 outline-previous-heading outline-previous-visible-heading looking-at level outline-regexp] 3 (/usr/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/outline.elc . 34670) p] 0)
```

How can I make org-mode open files in a folded state and not try to sort my headings when I open new files?

Using spacemacs 0.200.13 @ emacs 26.3.
the relevant variables/settings are:

```
  ;; Org mode settings
  (defun org-sort-headings-todo-prio ()
    "sort org headings first by priority then by todo order"
    (interactive)
    (org-sort-entries t ?p )
    (outline-up-heading)
    (org-sort-entries t ?o ))

  (setq org-image-actual-width 400
        org-startup-with-inline-images t
        org-directory "~/path/to/folder/"
        org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "organizer.org")
        org-startup-folded t)

  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (yas-minor-mode)
              (make-variable-buffer-local 'yas/trigger-key)
              (setq yas/trigger-key [tab])
              (add-to-list 'org-tab-first-hook 'yas/org-very-safe-expand)
              (define-key yas/keymap [tab] 'yas/next-field)
              (flycheck-mode 1)
              (flyspell-mode-on)
              (org-autolist-mode)
              (org-bullets-mode)
              (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x s") (org-sort-headings-todo-prio))))

  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c o") (lambda () (interactive) (find-file org-default-notes-file)))
  (global-set-key [c-x c-c c-r] 'org-preview-latex-default-process)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture)
```

the whole config file can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/mpDFJRmi) (just without the variable definitions at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is apparently linked to the manner in which `local-set-key` is being used in conjunction with the `org-mode-hook`; i.e., `(local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x s") (org-sort-headings-todo-prio))`

Emacs is being told to call the function `org-sort-headings-todo-prio` when running the `org-mode-hook`, instead of assigning `org-sort-headings-todo-prio` to a shortcut key.  Try something like this instead:

```lisp
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x s") 'org-sort-headings-todo-prio)
```